# Why scanf accepts chars for "%f" format specifier?

Tags: c, stdio

I'm preparing a simple program for my classes and found that `scanf` is not as strict as I expected:

```
int main()
{
  // Define variables
  float alpha;
  float b;
  float result;

  // Get user input
  printf("Type alpha and b. Space separated float numbers only.\n");
  scanf("%f %f", &alpha, &b);
  printf("%f %f\n", alpha, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Returns:

```
Type alpha and b. Space separated float numbers only.
a 0
-29768832.000000 0.000000
```

Where I can read about its behavior?

How can I make input strict with standard functions and throw an exception if there was neither ints nor floats?

P. S. I'm using gcc v5 in Ubuntu.

Comment: *How can I .. throw an exception* - There are no exceptions in C.

Comment: You could start by checking the return value from `scanf` to see if it read anything at all or not.

Comment: "Where I can read about its behavior?" -- [the best place is the Standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2)

Comment: ... or the documentation for your C library.  On a Unix-flavored system, you can find that in its manual page (`man scanf`).  For the Microsoft C library, look at the online docs.  Etc.

Comment: Better to post your own answer below as an _answer_ rather than in your question.  See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Recommend to roll-back your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm preparing a simple program for my classes and found that scanf is
>   not as strict as I expected

No, you didn't.

Given this `scanf` call:

> ```
>   float alpha;
>   float b;
>
>   scanf("%f %f", &alpha, &b);
> ```

... and this input:

> ```
> a 0
> ```

... `scanf` has a matching failure when it encounters the 'a' while trying to scan a floating-point value and not having yet scanned any decimal digits.  It stops at that point (and leaves the 'a' in the stream for a subsequent read), and, as always, it returns the number of input fields successfully scanned (0).

> Where I can read about its behavior?

You could try running the command `man scanf` at the command line (Linux, OSX, ...), or entering the same as a Google search.  Or google "scanf docs" or "scanf manual" or similar.  Or look up the official manual for your particular C library.  For standard library functions, [the standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2) is an excellent reference, but your particular implementation may have extensions not documented there, or occasionally may even differ from the standard in minor ways.

> How can I make input strict with standard functions and throw an
>   exception if there was neither ints nor floats?

C does not have exceptions.  It tells you about errors via function return values, for the most part, though some third-party libraries may do it slightly differently.  But you have to do *your* part, by checking the return values and responding appropriately.  In this particular case, you must avoid reading the values of `alpha` and `b`.  Because those variables were not initialized and did not subsequently have any values assigned to them, reading their values produces **undefined behavior**.

Comment: C does not have exceptions in the sense that OP is thinking of, but C does have a concept of exceptional conditions, e.g. floating point exceptions and integer overflow. Also, some functions set `errno` under some circumstances.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! So, if I get it right, I can just check is I have exactly two matches and return 22 otherwise.

Comment: @terales, yes, you check whether you have exactly two matches.  Any different result tells you not only that some fields were not parsed, but *which ones*.  You may safely use the ones that were parsed.  I'm not sure were returning 22 comes from, but if that's what you're supposed to do in the event of incorrect input, then yes, do that when `scanf` reports fewer than 2 matches (it will not report more).

Answer (score 3):

Others answers, especially [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252080/2410359) well explain why code fails to meet the goal.

Note input may converter to a `int`, `float`, neither, or both.

> How can I make input strict with standard functions and throw an exception if there was neither ints nor floats?

The best is to use other tools like `fgets()` to read a *line* of input and form a *string* for later testing.

To test *strictly* for is a bit hard.  `*scanf("%d",...)` has *undefined behavior* on overflow.  `*scanf("%f",...)` has similar UB, especially when `float` does not support infinity/not-a-number.

---

To test if a string convert to a valid `int`

```
bool my_isint(const char *s) {
  // Add to dis-allow leading white-space
  if (isspace((unsigned char) *s)) return false;

  char *endptr; 
  base = 0; // use base = 0 to only allow base 10 input
  errno = 0;
  long val = strtol(s, &endptr, base); 
  if (s == endptr) return false; // no conversion

  if (errno == ERANGE) return false; // too big for long
  if (val > INT_MAX || val < INT_MIN) return false; // too big for int

  // Add to allow trailing white-space
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) endptr++;

  // Add to dis-allow trailing junk
  while (*endptr) return false; // trailing junk

  return true;
}
```

To test if a string converts to a valid `float` is like testing for `double` when `float` supports infinity/non-a-number.  More later- GTG.

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thanks a lot, this gives me an idea about the underneath complexity. This is a totally manual approach which I feel is more supposed to be used in production rather in learning apps for sake of algorithms exploration.

Comment: @terales Post did ask for "make input _strict_ with standard functions". I saw that as seeking a robust solution beyond a learner's debut.  Else is it just `if (sscanf(buf, "%d",...) == 1)` and `if (sscanf(buf, "%f",...) == 1)`.

Comment: Thanks, @chux, I would try to be more clear the next time. I've added your and John's info in the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252080/1363799)) and [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252449/1363799)) kindly explained the question is wrong by itself, actually `scanf` doesn't accept chars instead of floats but omitting it. To catch this behavior I've modified the code in the following way:

```
+ #include <errno.h> // Error codes constants

int main()
{
  // Define variables
  float alpha;
  float b;
+ int matches;
  float result;

  // Get user input
  printf("Type alpha and b. Space separated float numbers only.\n");
± matches = scanf("%f %f", &alpha, &b);

+ if (matches != 2) {
+   printf("ERROR: Space separated float numbers only expected.\n");
+   return EINVAL;
+ }

  printf("%f %f\n", alpha, b);
  return 0;
}
```

**Appropriate only for simple learning programs you're writing during your CS degree!**

Otherwise, check [@chux's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252449/1363799) answer for a more production-like solution.

Comment: Minor: why hard code 22 and not use `return EINVAL;`?

Comment: Detail: `"%f %f"` will not insure "Space separated float numbers".  Try "123.4-567.8".  If  space separation is required, additional code needed.

Comment: — "Minor: why hard code 22 and not use return EINVAL;?" 
— Thanks! I just didn't know it's possible. Space separation is optional there, the main point is to prevent wrong calculations. Thanks a lot @chux!